# Is it possible to create a static tableview in a storyboard and add it programmatically later? (iOS5, XCode 4)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to create a couple of small, static tableviews and add them to a panel that I have which slides in and out. The panel is created programmatically so I can't lay the tableviews out inside it via storyboard, and anyway I'm not sure if this is possible anyhow: It seems the only way you can lay out static tableviews that work is in a tableviewcontroller, which takes up the whole screen.

If you can't tell I'm pretty new to iOS dev so if I'm not understanding some fundamental concepts here please feel free to explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course is possible. Here is how it can be done:

1. Drag a `TableViewController` to your storyboard.
2. Set its `Size` to `Freeform`, add an identifier and uncheck `Resize View From NIB`
   [image]
3. Select the tableview and set its content to `Static Cells`. Design your cells.
4. Set its size
   [image]
5. Now, wherever you need to instantiate it do it like this:

   ```
   // I am using a UITableViewController as an example here
   // you probably would like to set your actual controller subclass instead
   UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"staticTv"];
   UITableView *tableView = tableViewController.tableView;
   [self.view addSubview:tableView]; // Or add it to whatever view
   ```

Enjoy :)

Comment: looks very promising! will try it out tomorrow and accept if it works :)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for a project for a while ago before I decided to make a work around. It works great thanks @Alladinian!

Comment: Alladinian, hope you get to see this... so the above worked great for getting the tables to render within the panel, however for some reason the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method won't fire within the tableviewcontroller subclass I designated for it. How do I handle selection events for these static table cells? Storyboard segues don't work either.

Comment: @ruedaminute Segues will do the trick just fine, but if you want to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (for which I don't really see the reason) make sure you set the `UITableViewController` in your storyboard to your custom subclass and also use it in the snippet above.

Comment: Thanks Alladanian, yes I'm just trying to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath because I couldnt get segues to work for these cells. I assumed my segues were not working because they are not part of the main view but are a couple of subviews down. So segues work out of the box for you with the above example?

Comment: @ruedaminute Give me some time to test it and I will cook something for you :)

Comment: @ruedaminute Okay is ready. It just needed to hold a reference to the parent controller and push the controllers from parent (segues by default would push inside the panel, so you're right it's not as easy with segues. I will edit my answer to include this details). But the setup is easy and works like a charm, [here you go](http://cl.ly/3v3z2I0i0H2g3q1z2q1L) :)

Comment: Thanks again Alladinian you really came through, that fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

A `UITableViewController` isn't necessary to provide the functionality you need to manage a `UITableView`. I think what you're looking for is the "Delegate" pattern. Any `UIViewController` can be assigned to be the delegate of the `UITableView`. For example, I have a "static" table that shows some options in an app I am working on:

```
@interface LBOptionsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,
                                                       UITableViewDelegate>
```

If you're creating your table views programmatically, you'll probably either be creating them in `viewDidLoad` or `loadView` (if you're creating the actual view yourself). After you've created your tableView, assign the delegates:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Then your `UIViewController` subclass will receive the data delegate messages like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Not sure if this helps you. I have not played with Storyboards much yet.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks! I do understand the delegate part but haven't been able to get it to work with static table views. You said you have a static one, but you're not using storyboards, right? Seems that it may not be possible to do this with storyboards unfortunately. I'll keep investigating, but think I might start trying to learn how interfaces worked before storyboards came along

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** @Alladinian has the right answer! If you're using an property for the view controller make sure you allocate it if you need it to be called by other methods.

---

I've yet to find a usefully reason to use static table view cells over dynamic. Table views were pretty scary when I started iOS programming. I used sqlite in my first app **YIKES**.

So yeah, you should just import the UITableView Data Source and Delegate and follow up by adding the table view to your panel (assuming it's a uiview and you can add the table view as a subview).

Anyways in your ViewController.h include UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

Next, add properties for a `UITableView` and an `NSMutableArray`:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView* tableView;`

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* tableViewContents;`

In your ViewController's .m:

`@synthesize tableView;`

`@synthesize tableViewContents;`

inside `ViewDidLoad`:

`self.tableViewContents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cell 1",@"Cell 2",@"Cell 3",nil];`
`[self.tableView setDelegate:self]`
`[self.tableView setDatasource:self]`

In the .m file:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.tableViewContents.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    index = row;

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
cell.textLabel.text = [tableViewContents objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation-- I'm okay with setting up dynamic tables though, I wanted to use static tables to save myself the time of setting up data sources and all that in the code since the data won't be changing, but seems it may not be possible